# 'sudo apt-get -f install' error

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get

I am new to Linux. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 but I cannot install any applications in it. The error messages tell me there are unmet dependencies and tell me to run 'sudo apt-get -f install'. But running it produces the following errors.

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 178237 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libasyncns0_0.8-5build1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libasyncns0:i386 (0.8-5build1) over (0.8-4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libasyncns0_0.8-5build1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libasyncns0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libasyncns0:i386
Preparing to unpack .../liblcms2-2_2.6-3ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking liblcms2-2:i386 (2.6-3ubuntu2) over (2.2+git20110628-2ubuntu3.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/liblcms2-2_2.6-3ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/liblcms2-2/copyright', which is different from other instances of package liblcms2-2:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libogg0_1.3.2-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libogg0:i386 (1.3.2-1) over (1.2.2~dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libogg0_1.3.2-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libogg0/copyright', which is different from other instances of package libogg0:i386
Preparing to unpack .../libsamplerate0_0.1.8-8_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libsamplerate0:i386 (0.1.8-8) over (0.1.8-4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsamplerate0_0.1.8-8_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libsamplerate0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libsamplerate0:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to unpack .../libwrap0_7.6.q-25_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libwrap0:i386 (7.6.q-25) over (7.6.q-21) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwrap0_7.6.q-25_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libwrap0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libwrap0:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libasyncns0_0.8-5build1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/liblcms2-2_2.6-3ubuntu2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libogg0_1.3.2-1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsamplerate0_0.1.8-8_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwrap0_7.6.q-25_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command

sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives//var/cache/apt/archives/libasyncns0_0.8-5build1_i386.deb

then run

sudo apt-get -f install

If the problem still exists , repeat the above step ,for every dpkg: error processing .